# Man and boy left behind on damaged earth?

Tags: story-identification

What is the name of the sci-fi story featuring an old man and boy who miss (on purpose in the man's case, accidentally in the boy's) the last shuttle leaving a destroyed, polluted earth?

I read it as a child, possibly in an anthology for elementary students. It could have been an excerpt of a longer work.

The man stays behind on purpose, and in the closing scene he is showing the boy how to dig up the concrete and plant a tree.

Comment: It's not the answer, but your title brought to mind the William Tenn short story ["The Liberation of Earth"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Liberation_of_Earth).

Comment: Just asking, because this seems familiar: is this a really, really short story (2-3 page length)?

Comment: Not the answer (no trees were planted), but another William Tenn's story *almost* fits the bill, with a man and a child remaining on a dying Earth awaiting the Sun's going nova, the first on purpose, the latter almost by accident: *The Custodian*, in Asimov/Greenberg/Waugh's *Catastrophes!* (1981).

Comment: In the unlikely event that you are still around. Does this answer the question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/272267/short-story-id-earth-evacuates-and-one-person-stays-behind ?

Answer (score -2):

Is it Childhood's End by Arthur C Clarke? The description of two people at the end of the world seems familiar.

Comment: I appreciate all these leads. Thanks to all who contributed ideas!