# A story about a boy and his grandpa staying on an Earth as the last ships leave

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

If I remember correctly, the story begins as the last ships containing the last bit of human civilization are leaving the heavily polluted Earth to resettle elsewhere.  A man and his grandson have decided to stay on the planet.  The story is basically a conversation between the man and the grandson.  At one point, one of the ships dumps a load of garbage back down onto the Earth.  I believe the story ends when the boy (or the grandfather) finds a green plant growing up through broken concrete.

I read the story as a youngster, so it was probably in one of those literature compilations that one would have in their elementary/junior high literature classes.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24681/man-and-boy-left-behind-on-damaged-earth?

Comment: Oh crap, I guess it is.  I think I've actually seen that post before and forgot about it.  Thank you.

Comment: There's no accepted answer though. Do either of the stories mentioned look like they're a match for yours?